# Laravel. Add port to home url

Tags: laravel

Site use port 8080 on new server.

```
I need "site.com" => "site.com:8080"
```

How change base url in laravel for correct including css/js and redirects?

Comment: Do you need to tell Laravel to generate asset urls like `http://example.com:8080/css/myStyle.css`? Does your website work correctly when you go to `http://example.com:8080`?

Comment: Yes, i need urls like http://example.com:8080/css/myStyle.css

Comment: http://example.com:8080 - website work, but css try to include without port

Comment: how do you generate your css links? code please

Comment: example: `<link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we tried many things.

It seems it's a bug or something. They have it since Laravel 4 and do not want to fix it:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1833

The only solutions I see here are:
1. To use standard port.
2. To generate URLs manually. For example:

```
// in controller
$baseUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';

// in template
<link hre="{{ $baseUrl.'css/myStyleSheet.css' }}" ....>
```

Or you could set this variable in your top layout, so all inherited views have it.

Comment: I put, but no results

Comment: 1. May be, but i can't it now

Comment: These are not redirects. You're just getting your host with port in your controller, then pass `$baseUrl` var into the view and use it to manually generate URLs for assets. Just tried and it works just fine with any port.

Comment: No need to make generation urls, because all Redirects will still not work. Htaccess can help?

Comment: Problem solved. I edit file `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php` in function getRootUrl(). I add port `$this->cachedRoot = $this->forcedRoot ?: $this->request->root().':8080'`. Css/js and Redirects are work!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding the following line to boot() function of AppServiceProvider.php :

```
URL::forceRootUrl(env('APP_URL'));
```

You can also hardcode it there, but this way it uses the settings from .env file.

Warning: if the APP_URL is https, then I also needed to add the following line, or otherwise it would alter it to http (weird):

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, `URL` is actually, `Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;`.  You can (of course) define the namespace at the top of your file instead `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;`